# Is it recommended to write business logic in enum based singleton class?

Tags: java, enums, singleton

Spring framework has made designing very convenient for us. I was wondering if we do not have liberty to use Spring or any other framework, then how could we achieve Singleton behaviour for our service layer classes and other classes. Singleton is default scope of Spring bean. We know that there are several ways of achieving Singleton pattern. You can refer this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples#thread-safe-singleton) for Singleton Design Pattern. If I decide to go for enum-based Singleton approach for my service classes, I want to know your opinions on the same because service layer will contain business logic. So is it really recommended to write business logic in enum?

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is not how to implement a Singleton but whether a Singleton is what you want to use in your use-case. Should you find that Singleton is actually the correct choice to go, then yes, you should use an `enum` for the implementation.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your advice. I will take care in future. As this is conceptual question and not programmatic, I was confused while formatting this post.